# Finding an Implementation of a member of a base/super class

Tags: c++, inheritance, vtk, superclass

Ok so I'm learning about base/super classes/ inheritance/ and virtual functions in C++.

So below is a Get/Set function set up in a header file, I am looking at the mutator SetSize(int, int);

```
class VTKCOMMONCORE_EXPORT vtkWindow : public vtkObject
{
public:
  vtkTypeMacro(vtkWindow,vtkObject);
  void PrintSelf(ostream& os, vtkIndent indent);
.
.
.

      // Description:
      // Set/Get the size of the window in screen coordinates in pixels.
      virtual int *GetSize();
      virtual void SetSize(int,int);
      virtual void SetSize(int a[2]);
```

From what I understand about inheritance and virtual functions is that this is merely setting up the function, and will need to be defined somewhere else whether in this header or some other.  What I am struggling with is finding where SetSize is defined, I provide it values in my main, but where does Size get set to a variable and then where does that variable go in to a larger process that defines the actual window size.  Obviously I don't give you all the information to tell me where it is exactly, but I don't know how to figure out how it gets from calling it in my main, to setting the actual window size in the renderer.

I hope all of that makes sense and that I am using correct terminology, I would appreciate any help or further reading suggestions because I'm not sure what else to search to find this answer.

Below is the entire header file for reference

```
    /*=========================================================================

  Program:   Visualization Toolkit
  Module:    vtkWindow.h

  Copyright (c) Ken Martin, Will Schroeder, Bill Lorensen
  All rights reserved.
  See Copyright.txt or http://www.kitware.com/Copyright.htm for details.

     This software is distributed WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even
     the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
     PURPOSE.  See the above copyright notice for more information.

=========================================================================*/
// .NAME vtkWindow - window superclass for vtkRenderWindow
// .SECTION Description
// vtkWindow is an abstract object to specify the behavior of a
// rendering window.  It contains vtkViewports.

// .SECTION see also
// vtkRenderWindow vtkViewport

#ifndef vtkWindow_h
#define vtkWindow_h

#include "vtkCommonCoreModule.h" // For export macro
#include "vtkObject.h"

class vtkUnsignedCharArray;

class VTKCOMMONCORE_EXPORT vtkWindow : public vtkObject
{
public:
  vtkTypeMacro(vtkWindow,vtkObject);
  void PrintSelf(ostream& os, vtkIndent indent);

  // Description:
  // These are window system independent methods that are used
  // to help interface vtkWindow to native windowing systems.
  virtual void SetDisplayId(void *) = 0;
  virtual void SetWindowId(void *)  = 0;
  virtual void SetParentId(void *)  = 0;
  virtual void *GetGenericDisplayId() = 0;
  virtual void *GetGenericWindowId()  = 0;
  virtual void *GetGenericParentId()  = 0;
  virtual void *GetGenericContext()   = 0;
  virtual void *GetGenericDrawable()  = 0;
  virtual void SetWindowInfo(char *) = 0;
  virtual void SetParentInfo(char *) = 0;

  // Description:
  // Set/Get the position in screen coordinates of the rendering window.
  virtual int *GetPosition();
  virtual void SetPosition(int,int);
  virtual void SetPosition(int a[2]);

  // Description:
  // Set/Get the size of the window in screen coordinates in pixels.
  virtual int *GetSize();
  virtual void SetSize(int,int);
  virtual void SetSize(int a[2]);

  // Description:
  // GetSize() returns the size * this->TileScale, whereas this method returns
  // the size without multiplying with the tile scale.
  int *GetActualSize();

  // Description:
  // Get the current size of the screen in pixels.
  virtual int     *GetScreenSize() = 0;

  // Description:
  // Keep track of whether the rendering window has been mapped to screen.
  vtkSetMacro(Mapped,int);
  vtkGetMacro(Mapped,int);
  vtkBooleanMacro(Mapped,int);

  // Description:
  // Turn on/off erasing the screen between images. This allows multiple
  // exposure sequences if turned on. You will need to turn double
  // buffering off or make use of the SwapBuffers methods to prevent
  // you from swapping buffers between exposures.
  vtkSetMacro(Erase,int);
  vtkGetMacro(Erase,int);
  vtkBooleanMacro(Erase,int);

  // Description:
  // Keep track of whether double buffering is on or off
  vtkSetMacro(DoubleBuffer,int);
  vtkGetMacro(DoubleBuffer,int);
  vtkBooleanMacro(DoubleBuffer,int);

  // Description:
  // Get name of rendering window
  vtkGetStringMacro(WindowName);
  vtkSetStringMacro(WindowName);

  // Description:
  // Ask each viewport owned by this Window to render its image and
  // synchronize this process.
  virtual void Render() = 0;

  // Description:
  // Get the pixel data of an image, transmitted as RGBRGBRGB. The
  // front argument indicates if the front buffer should be used or the back
  // buffer. It is the caller's responsibility to delete the resulting
  // array. It is very important to realize that the memory in this array
  // is organized from the bottom of the window to the top. The origin
  // of the screen is in the lower left corner. The y axis increases as
  // you go up the screen. So the storage of pixels is from left to right
  // and from bottom to top.
  // (x,y) is any corner of the rectangle. (x2,y2) is its opposite corner on
  // the diagonal.
  virtual unsigned char *GetPixelData(int x, int y, int x2, int y2,
                                      int front) = 0;
  virtual int GetPixelData(int x, int y, int x2, int y2, int front,
                           vtkUnsignedCharArray *data) = 0;

  // Description:
  // Return a best estimate to the dots per inch of the display
  // device being rendered (or printed).
  vtkGetMacro(DPI,int);
  vtkSetClampMacro(DPI,int,1,VTK_INT_MAX);

  // Description:
  // Attempt to detect and set the DPI of the display device by querying the
  // system. Note that this is not supported on all backends, and this method
  // will return false if the DPI could not be detected. Use GetDPI() to
  // inspect the detected value.
  virtual bool DetectDPI() { return false; }

  // Description:
  // Create a window in memory instead of on the screen. This may not be
  // supported for every type of window and on some windows you may need to
  // invoke this prior to the first render.
  vtkSetMacro(OffScreenRendering,int);
  vtkGetMacro(OffScreenRendering,int);
  vtkBooleanMacro(OffScreenRendering,int);

  // Description:
  // Make the window current. May be overridden in subclasses to do
  // for example a glXMakeCurrent or a wglMakeCurrent.
  virtual void MakeCurrent() {}

  // Description:
  // These methods are used by vtkWindowToImageFilter to tell a VTK window
  // to simulate a larger window by tiling. For 3D geometry these methods
  // have no impact. It is just in handling annotation that this information
  // must be available to the mappers and the coordinate calculations.
  vtkSetVector2Macro(TileScale,int);
  vtkGetVector2Macro(TileScale,int);
  void SetTileScale(int s) {this->SetTileScale(s,s);}
  vtkSetVector4Macro(TileViewport,double);
  vtkGetVector4Macro(TileViewport,double);

protected:
  int OffScreenRendering;
  vtkWindow();
  ~vtkWindow();

  char *WindowName;
  int Size[2];
  int Position[2];
  int Mapped;
  int Erase;
  int DoubleBuffer;
  int DPI;

  double TileViewport[4];
  int    TileSize[2];
  int    TileScale[2];

private:
  vtkWindow(const vtkWindow&);  // Not implemented.
  void operator=(const vtkWindow&);  // Not implemented.
};

#endif
```

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. `setSize()` would be defined wherever `getSize()` would be defined. Typically, in the same translation unit that implements all members of this class.

Comment: Yeah neither are defined here, seems to be the way they do things many of the functions are set up but not defined, I've tried using resharper for VS2015 and still can't track down where it being defined an implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer to my question

In VTK all headerfiles header.h have a corresponding file header.cxx.  The function definition takes place in the header.cxx file.

Comment: Welcome to C++! You've identified an important and common pattern in C/C++ -- provide definitions in one file, and implementations in another.  I'm leaving a comment to point out [an excellent website tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/) touching on this topic and others.  It's also worth mentioning that you may see `.hpp` and `.hxx` file extensions for header files, and `.cpp` for source files.  Sometimes people try to use `.h` and `.c` for *pure C code*, and `.hpp`/`.hxx` and `.cpp`/`.cxx` for C++ code.  Not a standard, but nice to do if your project is mixed. Happy C++!